# iPhone CoreData Queries

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, fetch

I'm new at using CoreData and I'm trying to understand how to perform a query on a table.  I can use a fetch request to pull all of the records from a table, but I'm looking for a subset.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like:

```
// Init your fetchRequest
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityName" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedObjectContext];

// create the relation between request and the created entity
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription]; 

// Set your predicate for this request
// For more info take a look at NSPredicate Class Reference
// http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html
[fetchRequest setPredicate:somePredicate];

// Pushing the results into a mutable array
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[yourManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

[fetchRequest release];
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into [Predicates](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php#14)?

Also, buy [Marcus Zarra's book on Core Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356328).

Comment: Just to add, for the questioner's understanding: Core Data is an object store, not a relational database. You can have SQLite on the back end, but it's exclusively on the back end—you don't ever work with the database directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `NSPredicate` to the `NSFetchRequest` to filter the records that are returned. You can also control what is populated in the returned objects (only populate properties, include relationships, populate nothing, just return a count, etc.) but as Peter pointed out, Core Data is an object hierarchy and model API that just happens to store to a database. It is far easier to work with when you look at it from that POV.